# Cannot Reach Html File on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp

I have an Eclipse Java project, and I added a "folder" off of the root called "webfiles".  I then proceeded to create a file called form.html.  Once I run the project locally or publish it, I cannot reach the .html file.  I get a Not_Found error.

Is it possible in Google App Engine to use HTML files (other than index.html) and where do I have to place them in the project to access them by a browser?  What path should I use in the browser.

Comment: Where exactly did you put it? Are any other static files working (images, css, js)?

Comment: Project name is "BasicJava2".  I create a simple folder off of it called "webfiles"

BasicJava2 -->
          WEBFILES -->
                  form.html

What is strange is if I move it into the war folder with a static files tag it works.  How do I get the static files tag to work on the outer folder?

Comment: You need to put it in "war" or "webapp" or however its called. Where your .jsp are, too.

Comment: Thanks Thilo --> is war the only place I can use for the App Engine?

Comment: Why would you want more than one place? The URL root starts there, so it's not like it would be visible. `BasicJava2/war/abc.html` becomes `http://blah.appspot.com/abc.html`. (Again, not sure if it is really called "war").

Comment: If I create a folder under War, it works.  Also, I have to add static files tag into web.html.  http://localhost:8888/WebFiles2/form.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have /war/webfiles/form.html in your project than path to acces it from browser:

```
http://your_app_name.appspot.com/webfiles/form.html
```

To make reference from other jsp pages use:

```
<a href="<c:url value='/webfiles/form.html'/>">link to form</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add  include path="/**.html" " in your static files definition in appengine-web.xml else html files other than index.html would not even be uploaded.